# Taking too long to Read .psv file content on node js (over 2 million lines of data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have more than 2 million lines of data on .psv file and i'm trying to read that file using fs.readfile on nodejs and later spliting with pipe so that i want to read each line data from that .psv file. its taking 30-45 minutes to process this complete action. Is there any way to do quickly this complete process?

```
var fs = require('fs');

var firstLevelData = [];
var secondLevelData = [];
var filePath = 'sample-psvfile.psv';

async function readPsvFileContent() {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, completeData) {
      if (completeData) {
            completeData = completeData.toString();
            // console.log(completeData);
            completeData.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
            let rowData = line.split('|');
            if (rowData && rowData[2]) {
                let ovalue = rowData[2];
                let unique = ovalue;
                if (unique) {
                    let obj = {};
                    obj['index'] = rowData[1];
                    obj['name'] = rowData[0];
                    firstLevelData.push(obj);
                    if (rowData[4]) {
                        let ovalue2 = rowData[4];
                        let unique2 = ovalue2;
                        if (unique2) {
                            let obj1 = {};
                            obj1['index'] = rowData[3];
                            obj1['name'] = unique;
                            secondLevelData.push(obj1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: You can try to read the file line by line as in [these examples](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line).

Comment: The second example provides a faster way, as the old event API is currently faster than new async iterator API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will try it.